# How do I store attributes and values locally using Polymer?

Tags: polymer

My intention is to create a guided quiz but I would like to store things like names and choices completely locally. I followed the Polymer build an app in 30 minutes guide but they never cover how to persist data locally.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-localstorage

Comment: it's not really a polymer question. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: Thank you Paul for the links and information, it looks like exactly what I need.

Comment: If I might ask, are there any other tutorials you would suggest I follow with polymer?

Comment: I don't actually know of that many beyond the polymer-project docs, but I find this blog exceptional: http://japhr.blogspot.co.uk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you use **[json](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)** with an **core-ajax** element.

**mydata.json**

```
[{
    "question":"A question here",
    "answer":"The answer",
    "other":"and so on.."
},
{
    "question":"Another question here",
    "answer":"The answer",
    "other":"and so on.."
}]
```

**index.html**

```
<core-ajax id='ajax' url='mydata.json' on-response='{{response}}' handleAs='json'>
<template repeat='{{data in json}}'>
    <p>{{data.question}}</p>
    <p>{{data.answer}}</p>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        json: null,
        ready: function(){
            this.$.ajax.go();
        },
        response: function(e){
            this.json = e.detail.response;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you both you and Paul have given me a complete answer.